# I'm using labels in my code. But javascript keeps complaining 'label is not a statement.'

Tags: javascript

I'm using labels in my code. But javascript keeps complaining 'label is not a statement.'

```js
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  array1 = [];
  b = a;
  var val;
  var valIndex;
  var iCount = 0;

  a.forEach(function(aLoop, aIndex) {
    b.forEach(function(bLoop, bIndex) {
      if (bLoop == aLoop) {
        val = bLoop;
        iCount = iCount++;
        valIndex = bIndex;
      } else { //I want to move evaluation to where I have label 'loop1'
        break loop1;
      }
    });
    obj = {
      val: val,
      index: valIndex,
      count: iCount
    };
    array1.push(obj);
    val = 0;
    iCount = 0;
    valIndex = 0;
    loop1:
  });
  return array1;
}

console.log(firstDuplicate([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]));
```

actual result is crashing; expecting js object be populated with 1) elements that occur > 1; index of the last occurence of the element; and count

Comment: You can only use `break` to break out of a `for` or `while` loop. You can't use it to break out of a function.

Comment: loop1: at the end could be the problem but not sure.

Comment: Why do you want to use labels? Is there a specific requirement, or can you write that code without them?

Comment: Thank you much! I only use label as a means to an end--i.e., I thought that was a way to break out of a loop. But per response here, you can't break out of a function. Apologies for the elementary questions I asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `break` out of a `Array.forEach` function.

- You are using the post increment operator which won't work in this case. Here  `iCount = iCount++;` will evaluate `iCount` as 0.
- You also need to find the previous object inserted when there is a duplicate found in `array1` and then increment its count. You can do this by using `Array.find`.
- If a duplicate  is found by comparing the `aIndex` and `bIndex` then we are pushing a new object into `array1` with count as 1. If it is again encountered later we simply find the inserted object and increase the count and record the index in an array.

```js
function firstDuplicate(a) {
  array1 = [];
  a.forEach(function(aLoop, aIndex) {
    a.forEach(function(bLoop, bIndex) {
      if (bIndex > aIndex && bLoop === aLoop) {
          let dup = array1.find(o => o.val === bLoop);
          if(!dup){
           obj = {
             val: bLoop,
             index: [aIndex, bIndex],
             count: 1
           };
           array1.push(obj);
          }else{
           dup.count = dup.count + 1;
           dup.index = !dup.index.includes(bIndex) ? [bIndex].concat(dup.index) : dup.index;
          }
      } 
    });
  });
  return array1;
}

console.log(firstDuplicate([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 2, 3]));
```